# Network screensaver group policy

Tags: group-policy, screensaver

Inside our organisation we have a GPO that forces specific screensaver from a network location.

We would like to let one user access the location and override the screensaver file every week, however this is not possible right now, as the screensaver file is in use, therefore it can not be overwritten.

Is there any possibility to override the current screensaver file without stopping the GPO and restarting it?

Editting the rule for the new specific screensaver file every week seems quite clumpy to me.

Comment: You could have two GPOs pointing to two separate screensavers. Change the screensaver file right before activating the corresponding GPO. You can even give the responsible user permission to modify just these 2 GPOs if they're not a network admin. Keep in mind it takes about 8 hours for a GP to take effect.

Comment: Another idea would be to point the screensaver GPO to a local location on the PCs and use a script that runs on workstation startup to copy whatever the current screensaver is from the network location to the local machine.

Comment: Why not use the GPO to copy the screensaver over to a specific location on the local disk (C:\Screensaver or whatever) then have that file do a replace.

Answer (score 0):

Either assign the computer/user to an OU that the GPO doesn't apply to, or deny access to the GPO for that user/computer.

Then apply a different GPO and/or method for assigning that user/computer a different screensaver setup (i.e.: allow them to change it as needed).